# Can not add repositories in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: apt, 17.04, repository, ubuntu-gnome, add-apt-repository

I have tried adding various third party repositories, and I get the same error with all of them.

When I try to add third party repositories through the GUI "Other Software" section, I can open the box to add it, but it does not get added to the list.

When I try to add repositories from Terminal, I get the following output.

```
pal@pal-Vostro-3546:~$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
[sudo] password for pal: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 358, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 94, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 112, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 478, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3172)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 122, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 864, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 430, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 387, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 370, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 327, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 112, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 478, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3172)
```

What is the reason for this error, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm on 18.04 with exactly the same errors suddenly, but have just started investigating.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Didn't manage to solve it, had to do a fresh install.

Comment: Ouch, that must have hurt. I did solve my problem doing "sudo dpkg --configure -a ". Thanks for the feedback @Revetahw.

Comment: @Melebius I'm curious, how did you know we were commenting right now? It's such an old question with no recent activity.

Comment: @Melebius He is on a different version of Ubuntu, so it's not exactly the same problem. Also I guess this question should be closed now, as 17.04 has reached EOL?

Comment: Well I posted my solution, just in case. After all, this was one of the first google gave me when searching for a solution. Thanks guys.

Comment: Your question has appeared on the home page somehow as _modified by Gavin Simpson_. Maybe he posted an answer first, then deleted it? I first thought your problem could be caused by 17.04 repositories no more being available – then it should be closed now. However, if this may appear on 18.04 and has a solution, then it should have an answer. You are free to _not_ accept it but other users might still find it useful and upvote.

Comment: @Melebius Well, this question was asked while 17.04 was still supported. I'm obviously not running 17.04 anymore, so I can't really test or vouch for the answer.

Comment: @Melebius Thanks for sharing how you saw the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the issues is from a corrupt or incomplete previous install, or a corrupt sources list.

The way to fix that is to use the line below to reconfigure the install.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

From a bit of googleing I deleted the sources list first, but it appears this is not actually required, but is worth mentioning in case the above fails.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

For the record I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I suggest to **move** the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` away instead of deleting them, as it looks a bit _extreme_ to delete them. You can also simply rename them to `.bak` or similar and they won't be picked up by `apt`.